# Can't get glassfish to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish

```
SEVERE: Local Exception Stack: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseExceptionInternal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.Error Code: 0
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HelloWorld">
        <class>model.HelloWorld</class>
        <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have the connector install on glassfish, with successful pings I just can't the servlet and entitymanager to get the query to the mysql server. Any help would be good, also tutorials as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Glassfish-initiated JDBC connection (I think you are since you say you sucessfully pinged the datasource), then you don't want to define the properties as you have them in the persistence.xml. You'll want to just specify a data-source by JNDI name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="HelloWorld">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myds</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>model.HelloWorld</class>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: When I do this I get
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: Persistence unit named [HelloWorld] is configured as JTA, yet only non-jta-data-source name is supplied in persistence.xml.java.lang.RuntimeException: Persistence unit named [HelloWorld] is configured as JTA, yet only non-jta-data-source name is supplied in persistence.xml.

Comment: That means you've configured that JDBC connection as JTA, just use `<jta-data-source>` instead of `<non-jta-data-source>`

Comment: ok I got the mysql all working now but this isn't JPA? So do you know a good tutorial on JPA, eclipse and glassfish? Google hasn't been helping me

Comment: This tutorial is fairly good, keep in mind that because you're on glassfish, you can skip step 3.1 because glassfish includes a copy of eclipse link already, and if you have included the glassfish runtime libraries, you'll already have included javax.persistance.*.jar.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html